# Using mutable or immutable reference in a string chars for-loop

Tags: rust

I'm confused how a mutable reference works in a for-loop while an immutable reference does not. Is it an iterator?

I found that after loop, the reference `chars` refers to value `""`.

### No reference

```rust
fn main() {
    let str_value: String = "abc".to_string();

    let chars = str_value.chars();
    for char_value in chars {
        println!("char: {}", char_value);
    }
}
```

```
char: a
char: b
char: c
```

### Immutable reference

```rust
fn main() {
    let str_value: String = "abc".to_string();

    let chars = str_value.chars();
    for char_value in &chars {
        println!("char: {}", char_value);
    }
}
```

```
error[E0277]: `&std::str::Chars<'_>` is not an iterator
 --> src/main.rs:5:23
  |
5 |     for char_value in &chars {
  |                       -^^^^^
  |                       |
  |                       `&std::str::Chars<'_>` is not an iterator
  |                       help: consider removing the leading `&`-reference
  |
  = help: the trait `std::iter::Iterator` is not implemented for `&std::str::Chars<'_>`
  = note: `std::iter::Iterator` is implemented for `&mut std::str::Chars<'_>`, but not for `&std::str::Chars<'_>`
  = note: required by `std::iter::IntoIterator::into_iter`
```

### Mutable reference

```rust
fn main() {
    let str_value: String = "abc".to_string();

    let mut chars = str_value.chars();
    for char_value in &mut chars {
        println!("char: {}", char_value);
    }

    // why chars equal ""?
    assert_eq!(chars.as_str(), "");
}
```

```
char: a
char: b
char: c
```

Comment: "Is it an iterator?" - from the error message: "note: `std::iter::Iterator` is implemented for `&mut std::str::Chars<'_>`, but not for `&std::str::Chars<'_>`", so `&mut chars` is indeed an iterator.

Comment: @ForceBru But what's the purpose to make mutable reference be an iterator, and immutable reference can't works.And why after the loop mutable reference refers to empty string.

Comment: The iterator becomes empty after you iterated over it because there's nothing more to iterate over. It's like if you read a book by ripping out the pages you've read, you won't be able to re-read this book because it'll have no more pages. About the mutable reference, I'm not sure why this is the case.

Comment: @ForceBru yeah, that's my confusion.When I use a Vector mutable reference in a for-loop, finally the reference seems to be reseted.

Answer (score 5):

`chars` is of type [`Chars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html) which [implements ("is a") iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html#implementations) whose elements are of type [`char`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/str/mod.rs.html#565).

In Rust, you can use [`for`-loops on things that implement ("are a") iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-02-iterators.html).

Thus, your first example is covered by this: Iterates over `char`s.

The second example does not work because `&chars` has type `&Chars` (a borrowed, immutable reference), which does *not* implement `Iterator`.

In the third example, however, you have `&mut Chars`, and [this is an iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/traits/iterator.rs.html#2989-2996):

> ```
> impl<I: Iterator + ?Sized> Iterator for &mut I {
>     type Item = I::Item;
>     fn next(&mut self) -> Option<I::Item> { (**self).next() }
>     // some details omitted
> }
> ```

The above says: For any type `I` that is an `Iterator` and that may not satisfy `?Sized` (all this holds for the type `Chars`), the type `&mut I` is an `Iterator`, whose iterated values are the same as the original iterated types (`type Item = I::Item`), and that delegates `next` (and some other methods) to the original iterator.

Thus, the third example sees `&mut Chars`, knows that `Chars` is an `Iterator`, and infers that then `&mut Chars` is also an `Iterator` that can be used in a `for`-loop.

[`as_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html#method.as_str) -- according to its documentation (see the example there) gives you the remaining (i.e. not yet iterated) substring, so after the iteration, it should just say `""` (i.e. empty), since there is nothing left to be iterated over.